# What are Facebook Messenger audio message formats?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, audio, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm using Facebook Messenger to send an audio file to my bot. The webhook call that Facebook sends me includes a URL, which is the audio file and when I download it it's in .mp4 format (weird, since it's supposed to be audio not video).

I didn't find any documentation as to why it's .mp4, and whether there is the option to get a different format from Facebook. Anyone knows anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia, as found by searching for "mpeg 4 audio" using Google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14)

> MPEG-4 Part 14 or MP4 is a digital multimedia container format most
>   commonly used to store video and audio, but it can also be used to
>   store other data such as subtitles and still images.

I can confirm this is the case as I've pulled one of these files down as well.

Answer (score 0):

From Meta I found this website:

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/162540111070395?id=1123223941353904

From german Wikipedia I found this information

(https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP4)

MP-4 file formats can accommodate a variety of different media types and store them with structural information and their dependencies.
Multimedia content in the form of multiple audio and video tracks as well as subtitles, 2D and 3D graphics can be saved in MP4 files.
[...]
However, it is not common practice to include all available formats in MP4 in order to ensure compatibility between different applications, although this would theoretically be possible through "private" labelling (flags or atoms). MPEG has therefore limited the container to the following formats:

1. video: MPEG-H Part 2 (HEVC/H.265), MPEG-4 Part 10 (AVC/H.264), MPEG-4 Part 2, MPEG-2 Video and MPEG-1 Video
2. audio: MPEG-4 Part 3, AAC, MP3, MP2, MP1
3. images: JPEG, PNG
4. graphics and text: BIFS (e.g. subtitles can be converted to this format)